# Node's Package Manager warning

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to install Hoodie
and after following the first steps in this tutorial http://www.sitepoint.com/tutorial-getting-started-hoodie/

in the step:
$brew install node

it shows me 
Warning: node-0.10.33 already installed, it's just not linked

what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

To the first part of the question, this error means that you already have node installed on your system.  You can likely find that install by using the command:

```
which node
```

Failing that,

```
locate node
```

I don't find any specific reference to the "it's just not linked" error statement, but the homebrew wiki refers to linking with the

```
brew link
```

command if/when the system fails to link (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md#what-does-keg-only-mean)

The error itself would come out of homebrew/install.rb line 46 (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/face2a37b011856b270e7d95b305f31994b3a662/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb)